# Uploading video using URL swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to upload a video to server using alamofire. The user selects the video and I get URL in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo successfully as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let pickedVideo = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
            print(pickedVideo)
        }
    }
```

And then I upload the video using the following code:

```
Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(videoUrl, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")

        }, to: url, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                        completion(true)
                    } else {
                        completion(false)
                        print(response)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                completion(false)
            }
        })
```

It enters in the failure block, and the following error displays:

> multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(atURL:
>   file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C662AB0E-6A4F-40FB-9949-7F0A5AA2BA49/tmp/52C86F07-5DCC-413A-9F8C-71BBF33F793C.MOV
>   -- file:///, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “52C86F07-5DCC-413A-9F8C-71BBF33F793C.MOV” couldn’t be opened because
>   there is no such file.

Comment: Video can't upload via URL, convert it to `Data` object and then upload it.

Comment: show us the code where you create your `videoUrl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to upload video by URL, that is not possible, in `multipartFormData` need data to upload not URL, so firstly convert it to `Data` then upload it.

Function for show imagePickerController only for Video's:

```
func showImagePicker(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` function, that work after select video:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            guard let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: videoUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
                print(data)
//  here you can see data bytes of selected video, this data object is upload to server by multipartFormData upload
            } catch  {
            }
        }
```

Comment: the message displaying is "The file “2C6D0E52-482B-4D8E-B3B7-F8B9CDF3E858.MOV” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Comment: Yes now i am converting my url to data object.

Comment: When converting url to data, the data is nil. I think url is not being generated properly

Comment: Data object is empty that is why I am unable to upload it.

Comment: I think url is not correct, that is why program is unable to convert url into data object, hence returning data object as nil. I am getting such a url:   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B5BF6C95-3708-4A94-9485-0AE01F0AFF31/tmp/C81EE7B5-B8BA-4915-8851-FCD33B93703A.MOV

Comment: what is output of `print(data)` statement?

Comment: Issue was at my end. Thanks @Rocky for your help.

Comment: @MuneebRehman What was the issue. ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Why `as NSString as String`?

Answer (score 4):

With Alamofire 5 , you can do this to upload a video to server:

```
 import Alamofire

 func uploadVideo(videoUrl: URL) { // local video file path..
        let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 // just for some random name.

        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(videoUrl, withName: "image", fileName: "\(timestamp).mp4", mimeType: "\(timestamp)/mp4")
        }, to: endPoint!  ).responseJSON { (response) in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
    }
```

> Note: endPoint is a string . Example: http://172.10.3.7:5000/uploadvideo

Answer (score 0):

.responseJSON depreciated
use .responseData instead

example:
[Update responseJSON to responseDecodable in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789753/update-responsejson-to-responsedecodable-in-swift)