# Update responseJSON to responseDecodable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to upgrade some old Swift code. I'm getting the below warning:

> 'responseJSON(queue:dataPreprocessor:emptyResponseCodes:emptyRequestMethods:options:completionHandler:)'
> is deprecated: responseJSON deprecated and will be removed in
> Alamofire 6. Use responseDecodable instead.

...in the below code:

```
extension Alamofire.DataRequest {
    func json(_ options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments, successHandler: ((Any?) -> Void)? = nil, failureHandler: ((AFDataResponse<Any>) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
        return responseJSON() {
            response in
            if UtilityService.ensureSuccessful(response, failureHandler: { failureHandler?(response) }) {
                successHandler?(response.value)
            }
            NetworkActivityManager.sharedInstance.decrementActivityCount()
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace responseJSON with responseDecodable, I get this error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

What do I need to do to update this code?

Comment: You'll want to actually decode your response into a `Decodable` type and provide that type to `responseDecodable`. Then update your surrounding methods to use a generic rather than `Any`.

Comment: Do you use `Codable`, Swift Feature for decoding JSON? If not, you can still use  `responseData()` and call yourself `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` on it.

Comment: @Larme That was it...I'm not using Codable. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) recommends to use `responseDecodable()` because people were often using `responseJSON()`, then get the `response.data`, and call a `JSONDecoder()` on it. So this was making inner call of `JSONSerialization` for "nothing". Also, since Codable is "new", and there were still old questions available, people could be missing the Codable feature. See [this topic](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/3502) on Alamofire Repo.
So if you use `Codable`, I encourage it when possible, use `responseDecodable()` instead.

But, you still can do it manually, by retrieving `Data` with no conversion:

For that, use:

```
@discardableResult func responseData(queue: DispatchQueue = .main, dataPreprocessor: DataPreprocessor = DataResponseSerializer.defaultDataPreprocessor, emptyResponseCodes: Set<Int> = DataResponseSerializer.defaultEmptyResponseCodes, emptyRequestMethods: Set<HTTPMethod> = DataResponseSerializer.defaultEmptyRequestMethods, completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Data>) -> Void) -> Self
```

In use:

```
request.responseData { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let asJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                // Handle as previously success
            } catch {
                // Here, I like to keep a track of error if it occurs, and also print the response data if possible into String with UTF8 encoding
                // I can't imagine the number of questions on SO where the error is because the API response simply not being a JSON and we end up asking for that "print", so be sure of it
                print("Error while decoding response: "\(error)" from: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            // Handle as previously error
        }
}
```

Comment: You can copy the context of the `JSONResponseSerializer` which, while deprecated, as not yet been removed, and make your own serializer as well.

Comment: Indeed, but since the question was to prepare for next release and remove deprecated code, using `JSONResponseSerializer` would be more or less using the author code, since I guess (I didn't check) that's what's under the hood of `responseJSON()`...

Comment: This change actually doesn't make a ton of sense. If you legit need it to convert to a dictionary now you need to do the same thing the old method was doing yourself. What the hell.

Comment: @smileBot Feel free to comment on their repo, I gave the discussion link (which might be closed), but you could open an issue with that.

Comment: Thanks, going to use responseData + manual deserialization. That deprecation is really annoying.

Answer (score 5):

```
AF.request(apiURL).responseDecodable(of: User.self) { response in
   switch response.result {
   case let .success(data):
     onSuccess(data)
   case let .failure(error):
     onError(error)
    }
   }
```

That's my code for 'Alamofire', '~> 5.6.2'