# responseJSON deprecated and will be removed in Alamofire 6. Use responseDecodable instead

Tags: swift

In swift, when i use the following code:

```
final class EdamamSession: AlamofireSession {
    func request(url: URL, callback: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Any>) -> Void) {
        AF.request(url).responseJSON { dataResponse in
            callback(dataResponse)
        }
    }
}
```

I get this warning : `'responseJSON(queue:dataPreprocessor:emptyResponseCodes:emptyRequestMethods:options:completionHandler:)' is deprecated: responseJSON deprecated and will be removed in Alamofire 6. Use responseDecodable instead.`

Then when I replace "responseJSON" with "responseDecodable", then I get this error "Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'".

Any solution Please?

Comment: Do you use `Codable` struct? If not, I'd recommend often to use it, else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789753/update-responsejson-to-responsedecodable-in-swift/70804441#70804441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I am using `Alamofire 5.5.0`

```
final class EdamamSession: Session {
    func request<T: Decodable>(url: URL, callback: @escaping (DataResponse<T, AFError>) -> Void) {
        AF.request(url).responseDecodable { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
            callback(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new in swift, for that, i found that i must modify this protocol, how I can edit it?:->


protocol AlamofireSession {
    func request(url: URL, callback: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Any>) -> Void)
}

Comment: I edited it, Now the error hidden:

protocol AlamofireSession {
    func request(url: URL, callback: @escaping (AFDataResponse<RecipesSearch>) -> Void)
}

Answer (score 2):

Just change

AF.request(url).response**JSON**
to
AF.request(url).response**Data**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).