# How to use responseDecodable instead of responseJSON using Alamofire 6

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

One of my apps no longer works due to JSON serialisation failing when using Alamofire.

> 'responseJSON(queue:dataPreprocessor:emptyResponseCodes:emptyRequestMethods:options:completionHandler:)'
> is deprecated: responseJSON deprecated and will be removed in
> Alamofire 6. Use responseDecodable instead.

For code with the following lines

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in.. }
```

When changing to

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
 .responseDecodable { response in... }
```

Then I get the error

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

So I add the following

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
  .responseDecodable(of: ResponseType.self) { response in.. }
```

I get the error

> Cannot find 'ResponseType' in scope

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's deprecated, so it should still work. `responseDecodable` works if you have a `Codable` struct, which doesn't seem to be your case. Either use `Codable`, or serialize yourself using JSONSerialization. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789753/update-responsejson-to-responsedecodable-in-swift/70804441#70804441

Comment: You need to replace `ResponseType` with the actual `Decodable` type you want to decode the JSON into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike `.responseJSON` which returns a dictionary or array `.responseDecodable` deserializes the JSON into structs or classes.

You have to create an appropriate model which conforms to `Decodable`, in your code it's represented by `ResponseType(.self)`.

The associated value of the `success` case is the root struct of the model.

But *deprecated* (in a yellow warning) means the API is still operational.

Side note: A JSON dictionary is **never** `[String: Any?]` the value is always non-optional.

Answer (score 1):

In Alamofire -> Documentation/Usage.md, I found the definition of the Decodable, so I try like this, then found working.

```
struct DecodableType: Decodable { 
    let url: String 
}

AF.request(urlString).responseDecodable(of: DecodableType.self) { response in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let dTypes):
            print(dTypes.url)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
    }
}
```