# How to fix Alamofire responseJSON deprecated warning!!!! and how to use responseDecodable here

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am getting following warning on Xcode using Alamofire

> 'responseJSON(queue:dataPreprocessor:emptyResponseCodes:emptyRequestMethods:options:completionHandler:)'
> is deprecated: responseJSON deprecated and will be removed in
> Alamofire 6. Use responseDecodable instead.

Here is the code: this code is working but give above warning.

```
    let URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=\(videoId)&part=contentDetails&key=\(apiKey)"
    var duration = String()
    AF.request(URL).responseJSON { response in
        if let result = response.value as? [String : Any],
            let main = result["items"] as? [[String : Any]]{
            for obj in main{
                duration = (obj as NSDictionary).value(forKeyPath:"contentDetails.duration") as! String
                completionHandler(duration, nil)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help with responseDecodable for the above will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `Codable` (recommended), or recreate yourself the logic behind `responseJSON`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789753/update-responsejson-to-responsedecodable-in-swift/70804441#70804441

Answer (score 1):

According to your code the `Codable` structs are

```
struct YouTube: Decodable {
    let items: [Video]
}

struct Video: Decodable {
    let contentDetails: Detail
}

struct Detail: Decodable {
    let duration: String
}
```

Nowadays it's highly recommended to use the `async/await` API of Alamofire, and rather than calling the completion handler multiple times just return an array of strings

```
func loadDurations() async throws -> [String] {
    let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=\(videoId)&part=contentDetails&key=\(apiKey)"
    let response = try await AF.request(url).validate().serializingDecodable(YouTube.self).value
    return response.items.map(\.contentDetails.duration)
}
```

You have to wrap the function call in a `Task` and a `do - catch` block.